# Get values of a HASHMAP

Tags: java, dictionary, hashmap, keyvaluepair

I'm trying to access to the values of a pair from a hashmap. 
I have got a Map where Integer is the key and info is the value. 
I want to iterate through the map and get the specific data field (namePlayer) from the info object.

```
class info{
    public String namePlayer;
    public String knowledge; 
    public int coins;

    info(String nom,String coneixament,int monedes){
        namePlayer=nom;
        knowledge=coneixament;
        coins=monedes;
    }

    void setMonedes(int monedes){
        coins=monedes;
    }

    void setConeixement(String confianza){
        knowledge=confianza;
    }
    String getConeixament(){
        return knowledge;
    }
    String getNames(){
        return name;
    }
}
public class Memory{
    private Map<Integer,info> k;

    Memory(){
        k= new HashMap<Integer, info>();
    }

    void getValues(){
        Iterator it = _infoPartida.entrySet().iterator();
        while (it.hasNext()) {
            Map.Entry pair = (Map.Entry)it.next();
            info s = pair.getValues();// error
            String name = s.getNames():
         }
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the actual question?
getValues() is of type void, so it won't return anything?

Comment: First of all, it's `getValue()`, not `getValues()`. Second of all, `getValue()` will return you an `Object`, since you are using raw types.

Comment: An entry contains a key and a value, use `pair.getValue()` to get its value.

Comment: I want to print  ONLY the name of the player that has the key 2 for example .

Comment: Then you don't need to iterate over the entire collection. You can .get(7) the value from the HashMap.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the generics info to your `Iterator`

```
void getValues(){
    Iterator<info> it = k.entrySet().iterator();
    while (it.hasNext()) {
        Map.Entry pair = it.next();
        info s = pair.getValue();
        String name = s.getNames():
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

1. class names are upper case in Java (Info - not info)
2. k is an horrible name for a variable
3. This is very easy in Java

   ```
   for (Info info : k.values()){
       System.out.println(info.getNames();
   }
   ```

There you go.

For more information how to handle maps please have a look at the [dokumentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#values())

Comment: btw. Not sure if "in" or ":" is correct... doing a lot of python in the past ;-)

Answer (score 0):

```
void getValues(){
    Iterator it = _infoPartida.entrySet().iterator();
    while (it.hasNext()) {
        Map.Entry pair = (Map.Entry)it.next();
        info s = pair.getValues();// error
        String name = s.getNames():
     }
}
```

should be something like

```
public String getPlayerName(int index) {
   info i = k.get(index);
   return i.getNames();
}
```

Comment: Also, look at the comments and change your syntax... Classes should start with upper names, variable names should describe what they are containing.

Answer (score 0):

As Mr. @Lee pointed out.. you have to add generics to your `Iterator`...
 and `Map.Entry`

```
void getValues(){
    Iterator<Map.Entry<Integer,info>> it = _infoPartida.entrySet().iterator();
    while (it.hasNext()) {
        Map.Entry<Integer,info> pair = it.next();
        info s = pair.getValue();
        String name = s.getNames();
     }
}
```

Assuming that `k` is `_infoPartida`.

Also, consider @Rainer's 3 points.

Comment: @JohannisK, You are right. It just corrects the `getValues` method. This was posted before he updated his actual requirements.

Answer (score 0):

You have two options here. Either loop through using a for loop or an iterator. For loop is easy as shown by @Rainer however Iterator is more powerful because it allows you to remove the element you are one and has more functionality.